# Most frequent element in array algo, need python code converted to ruby

Tags: python, ruby, hashtable

Below is python code I wrote that will find the most common element in an array, I want to convert the below code to ruby WITH THE same FORMAT with ruby equivalents to the python keywords, i.e for python syntax "not in" I want to know the ruby equivalent to it etc..,all test cases should work.  Thank You!

```
def most_frequent(given_list):
    max_count = -1
    max_item = None
    count = {}
    for i in given_list:
        if i not in count:
            count[i] = 1
        else:
            count[i] += 1
        if count[i] > max_count:
            max_count = count[i]
            max_item = i
    return max_item

# NOTE: The following input values will be used for testing your solution.
# most_frequent(list1) should return 1.
list1 = [1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1]
# most_frequent(list2) should return 3.
list2 = [3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1]
# most_frequent(list3) should return None.
list3 = []
# most_frequent(list4) should return 0.
list4 = [0]
# most_frequent(list5) should return -1.
list5 = [0, -1, 10, 10, -1, 10, -1, -1, -1, 1]

result1 = most_frequent(list1)
result2 = most_frequent(list2)
result3 = most_frequent(list3)
result4 = most_frequent(list4)
result5 = most_frequent(list5)
print result1, result2, result3, result4, result5
```

Comment: Computer languages, like human languages, often don't map 1-1.  If you're going to use a different language, use *its* idioms.  Don't try to write Python in Ruby or vice-versa, follow Stephen Stills' advice and "love the one you're with."

Comment: I can't help it, here is a one-liner `array.group_by(&:itself).values.max_by(&:length)&.first || -1`

Comment: @maxpleaner Change the `-1` to `nil` or you won't be able to tell the difference between OP's `list3` and `list5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted Ruby Code:

```
def most_frequent(given_list)
  max_count = -1
  max_item = nil
  count = {}
  for i in given_list
    count[i] ||= 1
    count[i] += 1
    if count[i] > max_count
      max_count = count[i]
      max_item = i
    end
  end
  max_item
end
```

Note: Ruby guys don't write code like this there are more cleaner ways are  available in ruby to write this code.

in ruby instead of `None`  `nil` is used
if you want None in output then in the end replace `max_item` with `max_items || 'None'`

To print values of `result` use `puts`

Comment: If you ever actually want the correct counts, make it `count[i] ||= 0`.  You can actually combine it with the following line:  `count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1`.